# Recursively flatten child and return with full schema (Pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, nested

I have a json file containing nesting of sets with same names under attribute 'Tag'. The number of this particular nesting varies.Example:

```
{ 
    "Id" : "001", 
    "Type" : "Work", 
    "Tag" : [
        {
            "Id" : "a123", 
            "Location" : [
                {
                    "LocName" : "Astro", 
                    "LocCode" : "AST"
                }
            ],  
            "displayName" : "Al"
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : "e789", 
            "Location" : [
                {
                    "LocName" : "Cosmos", 
                    "LocCode" : "COS"
                }
            ], 
            "displayName" : "Tom"
        }
    ], 
    "version" : 2
}
```

I am trying to flatten the nested child recursively to follow this schema to arrive at a final output in this form.

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tag: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Tag.Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Tag.Location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |--Location.LocName:string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |--Location.LocCode:string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Tag.displayname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: string (nullable = true)


+--+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+
|Id|Type|Tag_Id|Tag_Location_LocName|Tag_Location_LocCode|Tag_displayName|version|
+--+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------+
001 Work  a123        Astro                  AST             Al             2
001 Work  e789        Cosmos                 COS             Tom            2
```

So far managed to use explode and denest the first set of the nesting and having difficulties with the recursive part (and to pipe out flattened child with the rest of attributes to become new row). Can somebody please help share the approach to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you already have declared the spark data frame, we can play with it to flatten your schema. You can do it in two steps:

1. Explode the arrays
2. Flatten the structure

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer


def flatten(df):
    """
    Create a new dataframe with a flat schema based,
    exploding the arrays and flattening the structure. 
    """
    f_df = df
    select_expr = _explodeArrays(element=f_df.schema)
    # While there is at least one Array, explode.
    while "ArrayType(" in f"{f_df.schema}":
        f_df = f_df.selectExpr(select_expr)
        select_expr = _explodeArrays(element=f_df.schema)
    # Flatten the structure
    select_expr = flattenExpr(f_df.schema)
    f_df = f_df.selectExpr(select_expr)
    return f_df


def _explodeArrays(element, root=None):
    """
    Explode the arrays to new rows,
    it only explodes one level of arrays. 
    """
    el_type = type(element)
    expr = []
    try:
        _path = f"{root+'.' if root else ''}{element.name}"
    except AttributeError:
        _path = ""
    if el_type == StructType:
        for t in element:
            res = _explodeArrays(t, root)
            expr.extend(res)
    elif el_type == StructField and type(element.dataType) == ArrayType:
        expr.append(f"explode_outer({_path}) as {_path.replace('.','_')}")
    elif el_type == StructField and type(element.dataType) == StructType:
        expr.extend(_explodeArrays(element.dataType, _path))
    else:
        expr.append(f"{_path}  as {_path.replace('.','_')}")
    return expr


def flattenExpr(element, root=None):
    """
    Flatten the structure of a dataframe
    (using '_' between level names)
    It doesn't work well with arrays, 
    you need to ensure there are no arrays in the input schema
    """
    expr = []
    el_type = type(element)
    try:
        _path = f"{root+'.' if root else ''}{element.name}"
    except AttributeError:
        _path = ""
    if el_type == StructType:
        for t in element:
            expr.extend(flattenExpr(t, root))
    elif el_type == StructField and type(element.dataType) == StructType:
        expr.extend(flattenExpr(element.dataType, _path))
    elif el_type == StructField and type(element.dataType) == ArrayType:
        # You should use flattenArrays to be sure this will not happen
        expr.extend(flattenExpr(element.dataType.elementType, f"{_path}[0]"))
    else:
        expr.append(f"{_path} as {_path.replace('.','_')}")
    return expr
```

So we can do something like this:

```py
json_test = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""{ "Id" : "001", "Type" : "Work", "Tag" : [ { "Id" : "a123", "Location" : [ { "LocName" : "Astro", "LocCode" : "AST" } ], "displayName" : "Al" }, { "Id" : "e789", "Location" : [ { "LocName" : "Cosmos", "LocCode" : "COS" } ], "displayName" : "Tom" } ], "version" : 2 }"""]))
json_test.printSchema()
f_df = flatten(json_test)
f_df.printSchema()
f_df.show()
```

So you get the original schema:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tag: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Location: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- LocCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- LocName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: long (nullable = true)
```

The new schema:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tag_Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tag_Location_LocCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tag_Location_LocName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tag_displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: long (nullable = true)
```

And the data frame:

```
| Id|Tag_Id|Tag_Location_LocCode|Tag_Location_LocName|Tag_displayName|Type|version|
+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+----+-------+
|001|  a123|                 AST|               Astro|             Al|Work|      2|
|001|  e789|                 COS|              Cosmos|            Tom|Work|      2|
+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+----+-------+
```

I expect this help you to think on your solution.

Comment: This is ! I was just going to write the exact same functionality, so you've saved me quite some time.

Comment: I really like this code! The only addition I would do it to add the usage of ` so it does not break on special characters or spaces in the column names.

Comment: @Axxeption May I know how to use ` ? I got a syntax error `Syntax error at or near '@' `

Comment: @ZahraHnn: you can use it as follow: expr.append(f"explode_outer({_path}) as `{_path.replace('.','_').replace('`','')}`") Unfortunately, I cannot add the complete code here.

Answer (score 1):

So there is no current way in a spark built function to do this. However, below I created a way for this to occur. The one assumption about this code however, is that I am assuming the length of the dictionary in which you are trying to process is not extremely large where it could not be read into memory in one go.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

inputs = { 
    "Id" : "001", 
    "Type" : "Work", 
    "Tag" : [
        {
            "Id" : "a123", 
            "Location" : [
                {
                    "LocName" : "Astro", 
                    "LocCode" : "AST"
                }
            ],  
            "displayName" : "Al"
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : "e789", 
            "Location" : [
                {
                    "LocName" : "Cosmos", 
                    "LocCode" : "COS"
                }
            ], 
            "displayName" : "Tom"
        }
    ], 
    "version" : 2
}

# Need to get all possible columns names beforehand
# This is so we can avoid schema conflicts
def get_column_map(input_dict, columns=[], key_stack=[]):
  for k, v in input_dict.items():
    if type(v) is list:
      key_stack.append(k)
      for list_item in v:
        get_columns(list_item, columns, key_stack)
      key_stack.pop()
    elif type(v) is dict:
      key_stack.append(k)
      get_columns(list_item, columns, key_stack)
      key_stack.pop()
    else:
      column_name = "_".join(key_stack + [k])
      columns.append(column_name)
  l = list(set(columns))
  mapper = {}
  for item in l:
    mapper[item] = None
  return mapper

# After knowing the column names, I can populate them
# One trick is that you should process all non-dict or list items first
# So you can easily append when you are at the last child in the nest
def process_map(input_dict, column_dict, key_stack=[], rows=[]):
  def order_dict(x):
    if type(x[1]) != list and type(x[1]) != dict: 
      return 1 
    else: 
      return 0
    
  input_dict = sorted(
    input_dict.items(), 
    key=lambda x: order_dict(x), 
    reverse=True
  )
  
  last_child = True
  for k, v in input_dict:
    if type(v) is list:
      last_child = False
      key_stack.append(k)
      for list_item in v:
        process_map(list_item, column_dict, key_stack, rows)
      key_stack.pop()
    elif type(v) is dict:
      last_child = False
      key_stack.append(k)
      process_map(list_item, column_dict, key_stack, rows)
      key_stack.pop()
    else:
      column_name = "_".join(key_stack + [k])
      column_dict[column_name] = v
  if last_child:
    rows.append(Row(**column_dict))
  return rows


# Can put this in a main or leave it in a functional way at bottom
mapper = get_column_map(inputs)
rows = process_map(inputs, mapper)
final_df = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
```

From running this code in my env I get this
[table/result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnucZ.png)