# Flatten Nested XML file in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nested, xml-parsing

I have the following nested xml file below which leads to my 2 questions.

1. **How and what** functions should I use to flatten the file into dataframe table? **Examples would be very helpful, please?**
2. How can I use field "CNTL_ID" (PK) to link it with "ENRLMTS" record? If this cannot be achieved easily, how can I create a surrogate key on the fly to link "PRVDR_INFO" with "ENRLMTS"?

XML File:

```
<PRVDR>
    <PRVDR_INFO>
        <INDVDL_INFO>
            <CNTL_ID>12345678</CNTL_ID>
            <BIRTH_DT>19200609</BIRTH_DT>
            <BIRTH_STATE_CD>VA</BIRTH_STATE_CD>
            <BIRTH_STATE_NAME>VIRGINIA</BIRTH_STATE_NAME>
            <BIRTH_CNTRY_CD>US</BIRTH_CNTRY_CD>
            <BIRTH_CNTRY_NAME>UNITED STATES</BIRTH_CNTRY_NAME>
            <BIRTH_FRGN_SW>Z</BIRTH_FRGN_SW>
            <NAME_LIST>
                <PEC_INDVDL_NAME>
                    <NAME_CD>I</NAME_CD>
                    <NAME_DESC>INDIVIDUAL NAME</NAME_DESC>
                    <FIRST_NAME>WILL</FIRST_NAME>
                    <MDL_NAME>J</MDL_NAME>
                    <LAST_NAME>SMITH</LAST_NAME>
                    <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                </PEC_INDVDL_NAME>
                <PEC_INDVDL_NAME>
                    <NAME_CD>I</NAME_CD>
                    <NAME_DESC>INDIVIDUAL NAME</NAME_DESC>
                    <FIRST_NAME>WILL</FIRST_NAME>
                    <LAST_NAME>SMITH</LAST_NAME>
                    <TRMNTN_DT>2010-09-10T13:19:38</TRMNTN_DT>
                    <DATA_STUS_CD>HISTORY</DATA_STUS_CD>
                </PEC_INDVDL_NAME>
            </NAME_LIST>
            <PEC_TIN>
                <TIN>555778888</TIN>
                <TAX_IDENT_TYPE_CD>T</TAX_IDENT_TYPE_CD>
                <TAX_IDENT_DESC>SSN</TAX_IDENT_DESC>
                <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
            </PEC_TIN>
            <PEC_NPI>
                <NPI>3334211156</NPI>
                <VRFYD_BUSNS_SW>Y</VRFYD_BUSNS_SW>
                <CREAT_TS>2010-09-10T13:16:28</CREAT_TS>
                <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
            </PEC_NPI>
        </INDVDL_INFO>
    </PRVDR_INFO>
    <ENRLMTS>
        <ABC_855X>
            <ENRLMT_INFO>
                <ENRLMT_DTLS>
                    <FORM_TYPE_CD>9999A</FORM_TYPE_CD>
                    <ENRLMT_ID>123444555666778899000</ENRLMT_ID>
                    <ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS>
                        <STUS_CD>06</STUS_CD>
                        <STUS_DESC>APPROVED</STUS_DESC>
                        <STUS_DT>2012-05-14T16:04:22</STUS_DT>
                        <DATA_STUS_CD>HISTORY</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        <ENRLMT_STUS_RSN_DLTS>
                        <STUS_RSN_CD>047</STUS_RSN_CD>
                        <STUS_RSN_DESC>APPROVED</STUS_RSN_DESC>
                        <DATA_STUS_CD>HISTORY</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        </ENRLMT_STUS_RSN_DLTS>
                    </ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS>
                    <ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS>
                        <STUS_CD>06</STUS_CD>
                        <STUS_DESC>APPROVED</STUS_DESC>
                        <STUS_DT>2016-08-09T14:33:40</STUS_DT>
                        <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        <ENRLMT_STUS_RSN_DLTS>
                        <STUS_RSN_CD>081</STUS_RSN_CD>
                        <STUS_RSN_DESC>APPROVED FOR REVALIDATION</STUS_RSN_DESC>
                        <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        </ENRLMT_STUS_RSN_DLTS>
                    </ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS>
                    <BUSNS_STATE>VA</BUSNS_STATE>
                    <BUSNS_STATE_NAME>VIRGINIA</BUSNS_STATE_NAME>
                    <CNTRCTR_LIST>
                        <CNTRCTR_INFO>
                            <CNTRCTR_ID>11111</CNTRCTR_ID>
                            <CNTRCTR_NAME>SOLUTIONS, INC.</CNTRCTR_NAME>
                            <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        </CNTRCTR_INFO>
                    </CNTRCTR_LIST>
                </ENRLMT_DTLS>
            </ENRLMT_INFO>
            <PEC_ENRLMT_REVLDTN>
                <REVLDTN_INSTNC_NUM>1</REVLDTN_INSTNC_NUM>
                <REVLDTN_STUS_CD>03</REVLDTN_STUS_CD>
                <REVLDTN_STUS_DESC>CANCELLED</REVLDTN_STUS_DESC>
            </PEC_ENRLMT_REVLDTN>
            <ACPT_NEW_PTNT_SW>Y</ACPT_NEW_PTNT_SW>
        </ABC_855X>
    </ENRLMTS>
</PRVDR>
```

Schema is below:

```
root
 |-- ENRLMTS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ABC_855X: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ACPT_NEW_PTNT_SW: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ENRLMT_INFO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ENRLMT_DTLS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- BUSNS_STATE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- BUSNS_STATE_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- CNTRCTR_LIST: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- CNTRCTR_INFO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- CNTRCTR_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- CNTRCTR_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- DATA_STUS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ENRLMT_ID: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- DATA_STUS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ENRLMT_STUS_RSN_DLTS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- DATA_STUS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- STUS_RSN_CD: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- STUS_RSN_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- STUS_CD: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- STUS_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- STUS_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- FORM_TYPE_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PEC_ENRLMT_REVLDTN: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- REVLDTN_INSTNC_NUM: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- REVLDTN_STUS_CD: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- REVLDTN_STUS_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRVDR_INFO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- INDVDL_INFO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BIRTH_CNTRY_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BIRTH_CNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BIRTH_DT: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BIRTH_FRGN_SW: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BIRTH_STATE_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BIRTH_STATE_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CNTL_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NAME_LIST: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PEC_INDVDL_NAME: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- DATA_STUS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- FIRST_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- LAST_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- MDL_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- NAME_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- NAME_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- TRMNTN_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PEC_NPI: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CREAT_TS: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- DATA_STUS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- NPI: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- VRFYD_BUSNS_SW: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PEC_TIN: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- DATA_STUS_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- TAX_IDENT_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- TAX_IDENT_TYPE_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- TIN: integer (nullable = true)
```

My current nested dataframe output below. I would to break this nested output to multiple rows if possible.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             ENRLMTS|          PRVDR_INFO|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|{{Y, {{VA, VIRGIN...|{{US, UNITED STAT...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Thank you much.

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: @Emma - I would like everything to be flatten. I would like to have 2 dataframes, one for PRVDR_INFO and another dataframe for ENRLMTS linked together. All rows to be flattened. No arrays basically.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63540987/2956135

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323562/how-to-parse-xml-string-column-with-pyspark